# When do integer dilations form a linearly independent set (or a basis)?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, schauder-basis

Let $H$ be some function space e.g $L^2[a,b] $ or $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. (Though I am happy to hear about other spaces).

Consider the sequence of operators $D_n:H \to H$ where $D_n(f)(x) := f(nx)$. (So I am assuming that $H$ is a space for which $D_n$ is a continuous linear operator from $H$ to itself.) Are there any theorems which attempt to characterize when $\{D_n(f) \}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} $ satisfies **ANY** of the following:

$1.)$ Linearly independent in $H$ 
$2.)$ Complete in $H$
$3.)$ Basis for $H$ 
$4.)$ Orthogonal basis for $H$

There are a variety of theorems which make characterizations of this form for other sequences of operators. Some examples of these operators are

1.) $T_{n}(f)(x) = f(x -n )$ 
2.) $M_n(f)(x) = e^{2\pi i nx}f(x)$ 
3.) $D_{2^n}f (x) = f(2^n x) $

All the characterizations I am aware of involve the Fourier Transform. Despite the usefulness of Fourier series, I haven't been able to find any similar characterizations for the integer dilations of a function.

Comment: "$D_n(f)(x) := f(nx)$" That is only going to work if the domain of the functions in $H$ is closed under multiplication by positive integers. Function spaces over $[a,b]$ will not work. If you want connected domains in $\Bbb R$, then $\Bbb R$ itself, $[a, \infty)$ for $a \ge 0$, and $(-\infty, a]$ for $a \le 0$ are your only closed choices.

Comment: Also note that if $H$ is a space such as $L^p, p< \infty$ which requires $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0\text{ a.s.}$, then $\lim_n D_n(f) = 0\text{ a.e.}$. But whether this almost-pointwise convergence leads to completeness depends on the norm of $H$.

Comment: We can obviously extend the function $f$ to be periodic. E.g $e^{2\pi i nx} \in L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: How would this point-wise convergence every imply completeness? That seems unlikely.

Comment: I didn't say it implies completeness. In fact, just the opposite. But if the norm on $H$ is such that convergence in the norm implies pointwise convergence a.e., then the only possible limit for a subsequence of $D_n(f)$ would be the $0$ function. So if $D_n(f)$ is complete, either it has no Cauchy subsequences, or else the Cauchy subsequences converge to $0$, which by completeness must be one of the points in the sequence. That is, for some $n, D_n(f) = 0$ a.e., which in turn implies $f = 0$ a.e. So the only complete $D_n(f)$ are either constant $0$, or have no Cauchy subsequences.

Comment: Yes I agree. Though I was hoping for theorems characterizing when it is complete or lin independent etc ...